# Reflection vs MEF or both

Tags: c#, reflection, mef

I'm creating  a CLI application that accepts a string as an input and calls a specific method from a list of plugins. The methods that can be invoked can have multiple, none or optional parameters. With MEF, the exports must have the same method signatures. I want the people that will implement the methods to provide only the necessary code and not deal so much with the integration.

The approach I thought of was using both reflection and MEF. Instead of metadata, I'll have the method name, paramtypes and required number of params as the contract. The main application will then invoke the method using the function name provided. I will need to validate the parameters first in the main app before invoking any method.

My question is, which is the proper way to do this? Please see code:

Original approach

```
    public interface ICommand
    {
        (bool, IEnumerable<string>) Execute(object[] args);
    }
```

```
    public interface ICommandMetadata
    {
        string Name { get; }
        Type[] ParamTypes { get; }
        int RequiredParams { get; }
    }
```

```
    [Export(typeof(ICommand))]
    [ExportMetadata("Name", "CustomImplementation")]
    [ExportMetadata("ParamTypes", new Type[]{ typeof(string), typeof(double) })]
    [ExportMetadata("RequiredParams", 1)]
    public class CustomImplementation : ICommand
    {
        public (bool, IEnumerable<string>) Execute(object[] args)
        {
            var result = MainImplementation(args[0].ToString(), (double)args[1]);
            return (true, new List<string> { $"Result: {result}" });
        }

        private int MainImplementation(string strA, double douB = 5)
        {
            return strA.Length + (int)douB;
        }
    }
```

If both Reflection + MEF approach, I'm thinking like this:

```
    public interface ICommand
    {
        string FunctionName { get; }
        Type[] ParamTypes { get; }
        int RequiredParams { get; }
    }
```

```
    [Export(typeof(ICommand))]
    public class CustomImplementation : ICommand
    {
        public string FunctionName { get { return "MainImplementation"; } }
        public Type[] ParamTypes { get { return new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(double) }; } }
        public int RequiredParams { get { return 1; } }

        private (bool, IEnumerable<string>) MainImplementation(string strA, double douB = 5)
        {
            return (true, new List<string> { $"Result: {strA.Length + (int)douB}" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's kind of an anti-pattern to have a method that doesn't define exactly what arguments are required.  Not only will clients not know what are valid arguments, the method won't know if what is passed is valid until runtime

Comment: That's why I require the parameter types and the number of params either in the mef contract or metadata - to be able to validate from the main application before calling the plugin method

Comment: Sure, but the problem with defining arguments in metadata rather than via the method is that it leads to alot of maintenance and ensuring that the metadata and business logic are in sync.   I think it would be better to define different `ICommand` interfaces with explicit parameters so as to encourage compile-time safety.

Comment: The methods will be provided as plugins. The main app does not have any idea of the different methods that can be called. Instead I provide an Icommand interface for the plugins. I think it's not possible to provide an interface for each different method signature implementation.

Comment: Maybe thats a problem that is better solved with polymorphism than explicit metadata.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Thank you!